# tex3D() Call Always Returns Zero

Tags: cuda, textures, multidimensional-array

I am trying to fetch data from a 3D texture in CUDA C, but the function call tex3D() always returns zero. Here is the relevant code:

HOST:

```
#define L 64
typedef uint2 splitspin_t;
texture<splitspin_t, 3> texRef;

cudaArray *arrayPointer;
cudaExtent LLLextent = make_cudaExtent(L, L, L);    
cudaChannelFormatDesc cf = cudaCreateChannelDesc<splitspin_t>();
cudaChk(cudaMalloc3DArray( &arrayPointer, &cf, LLLextent ));

cudaMemcpy3DParms params = {0};
params.extent = LLLextent;
params.kind = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;

params.srcPtr.ptr = h; // size L*L*L*sizeof(splitspin_t) allocated by malloc
params.srcPtr.pitch = sizeof(splitspin_t) * L;
params.srcPtr.xsize = L;
params.srcPtr.ysize = L;
params.srcPos.x = 0;
params.srcPos.y = 0;
params.srcPos.z = 0;

params.dstArray = arrayPointer;
params.dstPos.x = 0;
params.dstPos.y = 0;
params.dstPos.z = 0;

cudaChk(cudaMemcpy3D( &params ));

texRef.normalized = 0;                     
texRef.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;      
texRef.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp; 
texRef.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
texRef.addressMode[2] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
cudaChk(cudaBindTextureToArray( texRef, arrayPointer, cf ));

cudaFreeArray(arrayPointer);
```

DEVICE:

```
 #define GX (threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x)
 #define GY (threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y*blockDim.y)
 #define GZ (threadIdx.z + blockIdx.z*blockDim.z)

 printf("%lX %lx\n", tex3D(texRef, GX, GY, GZ).y, tex3D(texRef, GX, GY, GZ).x); // always prints zeros
```

I have verified that the memory pointed to by h is initialized nonzero. I have also verified that the cudaMemcpy3D was successful by zero-ing out h after the first cudaMemcpy3D, copying back to h from arrayPointer with a second cudaMemcpy3D, and then checking that h then contained the same data as before. I thought perhaps the problem may also be due to the fact that I was using a nonstandard type (uint2), but typedef-ing splitspin_t to float did not solve the problem.

I therefore suspect the cudaBindTextureToArray function call, but I can't see any mistakes I've made up to that point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to do this:

```
cudaFreeArray(arrayPointer);
```

until your program (or at least the kernel doing the texture accesses) is completed.

If you look at one of the cuda samples like [simpleCubemapTexture](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simple-cubemap-texture)  you will see the typical sequence is:

1. create the array
2. copy to device
3. bind to texture
4. call kernel that is doing the texturing
5. free the device array

Additionally, the values return by tex3D(...).x and .y are of int type.  If you use the long format specifier (`l`) with `printf`, you may get puzzling results.

The following code works for me, the above being the only two significant changes I made to what you had posted:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)


#define L 64
typedef uint2 splitspin_t;
texture<splitspin_t, 3> texRef;

__global__ void my_kernel(){


 printf("%X %x\n", tex3D(texRef, 4, 4, 4).y, tex3D(texRef, 4, 4, 4).x);

}

int main(){

splitspin_t *h, temp;
temp.x = 16;
temp.y = 65536;
h=(splitspin_t *)malloc(L*L*L*sizeof(splitspin_t));
if (h==0) {printf("malloc fail\n"); return 1;}
for (int i=0; i< (L*L*L); i++)
  h[i] = temp;

cudaArray *arrayPointer;
cudaExtent LLLextent = make_cudaExtent(L, L, L);
cudaChannelFormatDesc cf = cudaCreateChannelDesc<splitspin_t>();
cudaMalloc3DArray( &arrayPointer, &cf, LLLextent );
cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc3DArray");

cudaMemcpy3DParms params = {0};
params.extent = LLLextent;
params.kind = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;

params.srcPtr.ptr = h; // size L*L*L*sizeof(splitspin_t) allocated by malloc
params.srcPtr.pitch = sizeof(splitspin_t) * L;
params.srcPtr.xsize = L;
params.srcPtr.ysize = L;
params.srcPos.x = 0;
params.srcPos.y = 0;
params.srcPos.z = 0;

params.dstArray = arrayPointer;
params.dstPos.x = 0;
params.dstPos.y = 0;
params.dstPos.z = 0;

cudaMemcpy3D( &params );
cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy3D");

texRef.normalized = 0;
texRef.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
texRef.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
texRef.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
texRef.addressMode[2] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
cudaBindTextureToArray( texRef, arrayPointer, cf );
cudaCheckErrors("cudaBind");

my_kernel<<<1,1>>>();
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
cudaCheckErrors("kernel");
cudaFreeArray(arrayPointer);
return 0;
}
```

When I compile it and run it, the printout I get is:

```
$ ./t192

10000 10
```

Which I believe is correct.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head - once I moved the cudaFreeArray to the end of the program, everything worked correctly. 

Thanks for such a quick and thorough answer!